# Node&Express:req.flash() requires sessions

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I have some problems with connect-flash.
Here is my configuration

```
var flash=require('connect-flash');
var session=require('express-session');

 app.use(flash());
 app.use(session({
    secret:settings.cookieSecret,
    key:settings.db,
    cookie:{maxAge:60000},
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

I'm so confused and I don't know how to solve this

Comment: what do you mean by it requires session? what is the error are you getting?

Comment: whats the problem ur facing, plz share

Comment: i can't get my session data to `req.flash()`.So i need to exchange the position between `flash` decleration and `session` decleration in `app.js` ....

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `flash` middleware *after* declaring the session middleware:

```
app.use(session({
    secret:settings.cookieSecret,
    key:settings.db,
    cookie:{maxAge:60000},
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));
app.use(flash());
```

Express processes middleware in order of declaration, so when you use the `flash` middleware the session middleware has to be already declared, otherwise you'll get an error.